# Typescript Enum Comparison 'in' works but not '==='

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, rxjs

I'm trying to use Enum's to get a safe event output from an rxjs observable. Here is the full code sample:

```
// Enum
export enum Key {
  ArrowUp = "ArrowUp",
  ArrowDown = "ArrowDown",
  ArrowLeft = "ArrowLeft",
  ArrowRight = "ArrowRight",
  W = "w",
  A = "a",
  S = "s",
  D = "d",
  One = "1",
  Two = "2",
}
```

```
// Observable
export const useKeyboardEvent = () => {
  const $keyboardEvent: Observable<Key> = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(
    document,
    "keydown"
  ).pipe(
    filter((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      return !!Object.values(Key).find((v) => v === event.key);
    }),
    map(
      (event: KeyboardEvent) =>
        Object.keys(Key)[
          (Object.values(Key) as string[]).indexOf(event.key)
        ] as Key
    ),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  return $keyboardEvent;
};
```

```
// Subscription
React.useEffect(() => {
  const keyboardEventSub = $keyboardEvent.subscribe(setColor);

  return () => {
    keyboardEventSub.unsubscribe();
  };
}, [$keyboardEvent, setColor]);
```

```
// handler
const color = React.useRef<string>("black");
const setColor = React.useCallback((key: Key) => {
  if (key === Key.One) {
    color.current = "black";
  } else if (key === Key.Two) {
    color.current = "red";
  }
}, []);
```

When I log out different comparisons, I see this as the result:

```
key === Key.One false 
key in Key true
```

My question:
How can I compare so that `key === Key.One` succeeds? And why does that comparison fail, but `in` succeeds?

Comment: Log what the value of `key` is using `console.log(JSON.stringify(key))` Do the same for `Key.One`. You should see the difference.

Comment: Hey thanks :) So it looks like I was comparing the 'key value' to the 'value value', changing the mapping to `Object.values(Key).find((v) => v === event.key) as Key` fixed it!

Go ahead and post this as the solution and I'll approve it otherwise I'll update it by EOD. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are funny things in TypeScript. They're basically maps between a key and a value. So when you pass `key` you're passing the string `"One"`, but when you get `Key.One` for comparison, you're getting the string `"1"`. So, `"One" === "1"` returns false and you're stuck.

When you do `key in Key`, it looks for the property name `One` in the `Key` enum, and finds it, so it returns true. Of course, that just tells you that `key` is a member of the `Key` enum, so not very useful.

<sup>*As an aside, property names are called "keys", as you are likely aware, but I forwent the pun for the sake of clarity. But it was hard to do.*</sup>

What you can do is make sure you specify the type of the `key` as `Key` so that TypeScript does the correct mapping of value to value when asked to. As you discovered, one way of doing that is to change the mapping to:

```
Object.values(Key).find((v) => v === event.key) as Key
```